# How to change relative urls after the css file location has been changed by processing

Tags: node.js, webpack, gulp

For a typically web project, we may use `gulp/webpack` to packaging(compressing) the `js/css` to the **dest** dir. But the **images** do not need compressing.So that cause a problem: the relative path between image and css are changed, if I use a relative path for a **background-image** like `background-image:url(images/header_title.jpg)` will get a **404**.

What do other website deal with that? Appreciate for any suggestion！

Answer (score 0):

Check out [css-url-adjuster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-url-adjuster) or [css-rebase-urls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-rebase-urls).  They both will change, for example

```
background-image: url('coolImage.jpg');
```

to something you designate, such as :

```
background-image: url('/image_directory/coolImage.jpg?version=1');
```

[from the gulp-css-url-adjuster docs].

You just tell the plugins your desired new relative urls.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('style.css')
    .pipe(urlAdjuster({
       replace:  ['/old/path','/new/path],
    }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('modifiedStyle.css'));
});
```